# Is there any way intercept 'Back' keydown in Flutter app on Android?

Tags: android, dart, flutter

I need to show an alert dialog before user navigates away from current route by pressing `Back` button on Android devices. I tried to intercept back button behavior by implementing [`WidgetsBindingObserver`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/WidgetsBindingObserver-class.html) in widget state. There is an closed [issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/4867#issuecomment-276289384) on GitHub regarding same topic. However my code is not working as the method [didPopRoute()](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/WidgetsBindingObserver/didPopRoute.html) was never called. Here is my code below:

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class NewEntry extends StatefulWidget {
  NewEntry({Key key, this.title}) :super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => new _NewEntryState();
}

class _NewEntryState extends State<NewEntry> with WidgetsBindingObserver {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.removeObserver(this);
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Future<bool> didPopRoute() {
    return showDialog(
      context: context,
      child: new AlertDialog(
        title: new Text('Are you sure?'),
        content: new Text('Unsaved data will be lost.'),
        actions: <Widget>[
          new FlatButton(
            onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(true),
            child: new Text('No'),
          ),
          new FlatButton(
            onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(false),
            child: new Text('Yes'),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text(widget.title),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: new FloatingActionButton(
        child: new Icon(Icons.edit),
        onPressed: () {},
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I found the solution is to use [`WillPopScope`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/WillPopScope-class.html) widget. Here is the final code below:

```dart
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class NewEntry extends StatefulWidget {
  NewEntry({Key key, this.title}) :super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => new _NewEntryState();
}

class _NewEntryState extends State<NewEntry> {

  Future<bool> _onWillPop() {
    return showDialog(
      context: context,
      child: new AlertDialog(
        title: new Text('Are you sure?'),
        content: new Text('Unsaved data will be lost.'),
        actions: <Widget>[
          new FlatButton(
            onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(false),
            child: new Text('No'),
          ),
          new FlatButton(
            onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(true),
            child: new Text('Yes'),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ) ?? false;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: _onWillPop,
      child: new Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(
          title: new Text(widget.title),
        ),
        floatingActionButton: new FloatingActionButton(
          child: new Icon(Icons.edit),
          onPressed: () {},
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: hi Mal, i tried above onWillPop method its working only debug apk when i run release build on willPop not called.

Comment: in function _onWillPop `?? false`  should be removed

Comment: My app uses Navigator.PushReplacementNamed to move through its flow. I learned to always return Future<bool>.value(false) from OnWillPop() to prevent Flutter from popping the nav stack (which didn't exist). I had very erratic results until I started following this policy.

Comment: `onWillPop: _onWillPop` can also be `onWillPop: () => _onWillPop()`

Answer (score 3):

The `back_button_interceptor` package can simplify this for you and is especially useful in more complex scenarios.

https://pub.dev/packages/back_button_interceptor#-readme-tab-

*Example usage:*

```dart
@override
void initState() {
   super.initState();
   BackButtonInterceptor.add(myInterceptor);
}

@override
void dispose() {
   BackButtonInterceptor.remove(myInterceptor);
   super.dispose();
}

bool myInterceptor(bool stopDefaultButtonEvent) {
   print("BACK BUTTON!"); // Do some stuff.
   return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the GetX package and you implemented the `GetMaterialApp` method to initialize your app, the `didPopRoute` and `didPushRoute` methods in `WidgetsBindingObserver` never get called. Use the `routingCallback` instead, below is an example, for more info check out [GetX documentation](https://github.com/jonataslaw/getx/blob/master/documentation/en_US/route_management.md):

```
GetMaterialApp(
  routingCallback: (routing) {
    routing.isBack ? didPopRoute() : didPushRoute(routing.current);
  }
)
```