# How to handle back press in flutter on release build apk

Tags: dart, flutter, onbackpressed

i new to flutter, i try to handle back press event in flutter. it's works only debug build when i try with release build back press event not triggered i dnt know what mistake. Any help will be appreciated, thank you in advance.

i tried [WidgetsBindingObserver](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/4867#issuecomment-276289384) and [onWillPop](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44637374) both its work only in debug apk. when get release build using flutter build apk cmd(under the folder build\app\outputs\apk\release) back press event not triggered.

```
    import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:cryptocurrency_app/data/crypto_data.dart';
import 'package:cryptocurrency_app/home/home_presenter.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class HomeList extends StatefulWidget {
  HomeList({ Key key }) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _HomeListState createState() => new _HomeListState();
}

class _HomeListState extends State<HomeList>  {
  final key = new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
  _HomeListState() {

  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    // WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this);

  }

/*
  @override
  void dispose() {
   // WidgetsBinding.instance.removeObserver(this);
    super.dispose();
  }*/

  Future<bool> _onWillPop() {
    return showDialog(
        context: context,
        child: new AlertDialog(
          title: new Text('Exit'),
          content: new Text('Are you sure you want to exit ?'),
          actions: <Widget>[
            new FlatButton(
              onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(true),
              child: new Text('Yes',
                  style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.black)),
            ),
            new FlatButton(
              onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(false),
              child: new Text('No',
                  style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.black)),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var widget;
   widget = new WillPopScope(
          onWillPop: _onWillPop,

          child: new Scaffold(
            key: key,
            appBar: buildBar(context),
            body: new Center(
                child: new Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 16.0, right: 16.0),
                    child: new CircularProgressIndicator()
                )
            ),
          ));
    }
    return widget;
  }

  Widget buildBar(BuildContext context) {
    return new AppBar(
      leading: new IconButton(
        icon: const Icon(Icons.search),
        color: Theme
            .of(context)
            .accentColor,
        onPressed: _handleSearchStart,
        tooltip: 'Search',
      ),
      title: new Text("Crypto Live Rates",
        style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
      ),
    );
  }



}
```

Comment: What Flutter version are you using?

Comment: currently i am using flutter sdk master from git but i dnt know what version it is. is any cmd for check flutter version ?

Comment: `flutter --version` or `flutter doctor`

Comment: thanks for cmd, Flutter 0.3.1-pre.15 channel master, dart 2.0.0-dev.47.0

Comment: I think it should do the same in debug and release. If you can provide the code that allows to reproduce, it would probably be a good idea to create a bug report.

Comment: sure,  but how can i share code with you ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169537/discussion-between-magesh-pandian-and-gunter-zochbauer).

Comment: Ideally you'd create a GitHub repository that contains a minimal reproduction and then create an issue in https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues with a link to your GitHub repository.

Comment: ok,  i shared my code to you in continue this discussion in chat.