# Load 'editable text' from the database which users can edit directly

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have an app in which I would like the user to be able to change their description. The current process is for the user to click on the description which opens a new screen from which the user can update their description. Once the user clicks save they are navigated back to the previous screen.

Is it possible for the user to directly be able to edit the description and for it to save and update automatically?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use the [WillPopScope](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/WillPopScope-class.html) class to intercept the backbutton and save the change automatically when the user goes back.

An example could be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44637374/11266880)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [dialog](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/Dialog-class.html) or a [bottom sheet](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/BottomSheet-class.html) to prompt for them to update the description when they click it. You can then save this and update the label which will be done automatically if you set the value to a variable or use the real time aspect of Firestore. This then negates the need to have a separate screen.

Comment: Any chance how I can load the text from the database into a „Textfield“, to make it editable? Heard of steh like EditableText

Answer (score 0):

I got it working via a `TextFormField` to have an initial text value. Just define

```
TextEditingController _textController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _textController = TextEditingController(text: 'Your text');
  }
```

and replace `Your text` with your database String value. To save it, you can overwrite the `BackButton` behavior. Notwithstanding, to change the behavior for iOS swipe gestures is not that easy. Guess I have to look into `RouteObservers` to trigger a database save when the screen is popped.