# Flutter stateless UI life cycle

Tags: flutter

I have a Flutter app which is based on `StatelessWidget`. I saw an [example](https://medium.com/@marcoleong.developer/lifecycle-in-flutter-widgetsbindingobserver-2eb782236f8b) with `StatefulWidget` which allows the programmer to perform some actions in the `dispose()` method. I am trying to see if the `StatelessWidget` also provides such feature?

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'routes.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) { 
      return MaterialApp(
        title: 'My App',
        theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: colorCustom,
          fontFamily: 'Roboto',
        ),
        initialRoute: '/',
        routes: routes,
      ); 
    }

}
```

**UPDATED**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'routes.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {

  Future<bool> _exitApp(BuildContext context) {
    return showDialog(
          context: context,
          child: new AlertDialog(
            title: new Text('Do you want to exit this application?'),
            content: new Text('We hate to see you leave...'),
            actions: <Widget>[
              new FlatButton(
                onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(false),
                child: new Text('No'),
              ),
              new FlatButton(
                onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(true),
                child: new Text('Yes'),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ) ??
        false;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'My App',
      home: WillPopScope(
          child: MaterialApp(
              theme: ThemeData(
                primarySwatch: colorCustom,
                fontFamily: 'Roboto',
              ),
              initialRoute: '/',
              routes: routes
          ),
          onWillPop: () => _exitApp(context)
      )
    );

}
```

Hm, after updating the code, the `AlertDialog` does not pop up though?

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is no, there is no method similar to `dispose()` available in a `StatelessWidget` since as the name suggests, it does not maintain a `State`.

**The long answer is the `dispose()` mehtod -**

The framework calls this method when this `State` object will never build again. After the framework calls dispose, the `State` object is considered unmounted and the mounted property is `false`. It is an error to call `setState` at this point.

This stage of the lifecycle is terminal: there is no way to remount a `State` object that has been disposed.

Since the `StatelessWidget` has no `State` associated with it, there is no `dispose()` method.

**A similar solution for StatelessWidgets -**

So what should we do if we want to run some code only after the`StatelessWidgets` are popped from the navigation stack or return some data from the `StatelessWidget`?

Well, [this](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/returning-data) Flutter docmentation page has a this explained along with an example. Hope this helps!

Comment: How should I go about it if I want to perform some actions before the Flutter app exits?

Comment: You can use the `WillPopScope` widget for that. It has a callback `onWillPop` which will get called when you press the back button on your device. 
Wrap the widget inside your `build()` method with the `WillPopScope` widget and you can provide the actions you want to perform beform before exiting inside the `onWillPop` callback. Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44635450/is-there-any-way-intercept-back-keydown-in-flutter-app-on-android) question for an example.

Comment: Hm, how should I go about adding the `WillPopScope` widget inside the `MaterialApp` widget?

Comment: You can use wrap the widget you currently have as the `home` for `MaterialApp` with `WillPopScope`.